# How to delay the prompt for location services permission

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uialertview, cllocationmanager

In my app I'm using CLLocationManager and MKMapView. When app launches, I present the user with a disclaimer (once) which has to be accepted. However, when the disclaimer is shown, a popup appears requesting access to the user location.

Is there a way to delay this alertView until the disclaimer is accepted? 
Please advice.

EDIT:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"disclaimerAccepted"] == nil) {
    [self firstRun];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    [self locationStuff];
}
)
```

Comment: The question is not totally clear. Is it about suppressing the alert about using a user's location all together or having it displayed at another time than your disclaimer?

Comment: @ J. Gonzales: it is about supressing the Location alertView until the user has accepted the discalimer. When accepted the location services on the device are needed.

Answer (score 3):

The location alert view is only displayed when you actually request the user's location, so the simplest way to do this would be to ensure that the first time your app is run you start the `CLLocationManager` or display the `MKMapView` until after your disclaimer has been accepted. This may require you to move around some methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The disclaimer is now in my viewDidLoad method. Here I test with NSUserDefaults if the disclaimer is already accepted. (If defaults is not TRUE do firstRun method with the disclaimer else do locationStuff method. Still the AlertView shows during the disclaimer. Any suggestions? See editted question

Comment: BTW the firstRun method creates a subView on top of the mainView. In the mainView I use the locationmanager and th mapVIew

Comment: Could it be caused by the declarations of properties in the .h file?

Comment: @Adri It's certainly not because of some declarations in the .h file but some other piece of code - that we don't know about.

Comment: @J. Gonzales: I will dig some more.... thank you for your reply. I have some code in the appDelegate file but when I'm commenting it out there is no change at all. For now I don't understand where the alertview is coming form. The only thing I can think of is that the mainView is loaded, the mapView on this mainView is initialized and the subView with the disclaimer is loaded on top op the mainView. The mainView in this scenario is causing the alertView. Does this sound plausible?

Comment: @J. Gonzales and lxt. I've turned my whole solution up side down and back and I'm still presented with the prompt. In my knowledge the locationmanager is called after accepting the disclaimer. I've deleted the settings in the plist files but with no other result than stated. Any suggestions? I'm puzzled and... its the last difficultie in may app. Pleas advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need first check for disclaimer and if it accepted start `CLLocationManager`. If disclaimer not accepted - wait for acceptation and that start `CLLocationManager`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad]; 
   if (disclaimerAccepted)
   {
      //start CLLocationManager
   }
   else
   {
      //Show disclaimer
   }
}
- (void)disclaimerAccepted
{
    disclaimerAccepted = YES;
    //start CLLocationManager
}
```

Comment: @ Sergey: Thanks for your reply. I do not undertand your example code comleptely because I think I'm jus doiing what you are suggesting. The different is that I check for a value in the userDefaults and the other way around. Wich means: if the value in NSUserDefaults for the key "disclaimerAccepted" is equal to nil then do method firstRun, else do the locationStuff method.

Comment: The main idea is do not start `CLLocationManager` when disclaimer view is visible. But start it right after you hide disclaimer view.

Comment: I understand that and in my knowledge that is what happening. In my log the locationupdates starts just right after the acceptence of the disclaimer. Only the alertview show before. It puzzles me where it come from.

Comment: @ Sergey, did a lot of stuff in my code but no solution yet. Went back to an earlier snapshot. Any suggestion?